# Broadcast receiver with different intent filter action name for different product flavours

Tags: android, android-intent, android-productflavors

I have two variants of my app for staging and production environment which i want to install the app on my device at the same time, now the problem is since both apps have the same set of broadcast receiver with same intentfilters, the receivers of both apps gets called whenever any receiver is invoked which i don't want.

I have tried using different package names prefixes for intent filter action name using string.xml resources files for my specific product flavours but apparently you are not allowed to use string resources to specify intent action name in manifest.xml.

So what is the alternative and how can we do this?

Comment: Maybe you can do it at code instead of using the manifest?

Comment: that would mess up a good and nice working model, it seems the only product flavour alternative is having multiple manifest files but it is also not ideal, looks like i have no choice here, weird that you can't do this statically.